# Simplest way to assign value to a variable based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know a simplest and best way to assign a value to a variable if other variable is not null/undefined. This isn't the shortest and most elegant way possible

```
var name = 'Bob'

var surname = '';

if(name) {
   surname = 'The builder'
}
```

What I'd rather like to do is something like

```
var surname = if(name) ? 'The builder' : '';
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: even more simple `var surname = name ? name  :  ' ' ` 
more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: I don't want to assign value of name to surname but thank you regardless.

Comment: yes, my bad. should be `var surname = name ? 'The builder' : ' '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the ternary operator

```
var surname = name ? 'The builder' : '';
```

if name is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value surname will be equal to the string 'the builder', otherwise will be assigned to an empty string.

Comment: Could I be anywhere closer to that? :D Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`var surname = name ? 'The builder' : '';`

Answer (score -1):

**Unlike other answers**, this way, you change the `surname` value, only if the tested condition is `true`.

This means, that you don't have to repeat (and hardcode) the `surname` original value. (i.e. `''`)

```
var name = 'Bob';
var surname = '';

surname = name ? 'The builder' : surname;
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can have it in this format and omit the else statement.

```
var surname = names && 'The builder';
```

It is basically equal to

```
if(name) {
   surname = 'The builder'
}
```